# azure table storage space used

Tags: azure

How do I see how much data is in my table storage account? I have free trial and when I enable monitoring it has all kinds of metrics mostly related to errors, but I can't seem to find storage size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download your usage details from the account subscriptions page.  It won't tell you how much storage each individual service is using up, just the total on locally or geo redundant.

Go to the console, click your name in the upper right, then "View my bill".  From here you can view your subscription usage data and download a CSV of the details.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no Azure API to find billing and usage information, therefore, no applications can provide you with the exact figure that you would be billed. There is an open [feature request](http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/170031-sdk/suggestions/1143971-billing-usage-api) for this very issue. There is limited information available for blob storage, but I have found nothing for table storage.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Storage size consist of all of 3 services (Blob, Queue and Table) altogether however there are no ways to calculate the size of each individual service for now. The billing data also shows the cumulative storage size for an Azure Storage Service including all three. There are work items logged to separate the size data for each individual service within Windows Azure Storage however there is no further info on this regard.