# Get Details about Storage Accounts and Utilisation in a Subscription using ARM Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to find all Storage accounts (Blob and File etc) and Quota/Used space within subscription.

Could you please guide me through using powershell.

Thanks

Comment: Amit, could you please share with us what have you read and what have you tried so far to accomplish the task you would like to solve?

Comment: i am trying to use few powershell cmdlet combination like Get-AzurermStorageAccount ; get-AzurerStorageContainer ; Get-AzureStorageBlob ; Get-AzureStorageShare ; Get-AzureStorageFile.

Answer (score 0):

1. To get details of all your storage accounts within subscription, you could use `Get-AzureRmStorageAccount`,  and you'll get output like :
   [image]
2. Use Get-AzureRmStorageUsage to get current usage and limits.
   [image]

You can download your usage details from the account subscriptions page, see [azure table storage space used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623398/azure-table-storage-space-used) for details.

Comment: Thanks i will check the reference